# How to set fixed Marker position in Google MapView iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Here I'm working on `mapKitView` using `GoogleMapKit` and here i want to do when the user drag the marker by using of `didBeginDragging`, `didDragging` and `didEndDragging`
and release the `marker` at any location point of the screen. I found a helping content to fixed the marker in screen from [Hugo Jordao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48995067/11077258)'s answer, but this only works to fixed marker position in the center of the screen only.So how can i set marker at any specific screen point??

- Dragging Method

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didEndDragging marker: GMSMarker) {
        if marker == mapMarker{
            self.markerPosition = GMSCameraPosition(latitude: marker.position.latitude, longitude: marker.position.longitude, zoom: 5.0)
            print("End Dragging")
        }
    }
```

- Set Marker center to the Screen

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
     if self.markerPosition == nil{
         mapMarker.position = position.target
     }else{
         mapMarker.position = self.markerPosition.target
     }
 }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44736702/get-latitude-and-longitude-center-of-google-map?rq=1 go through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering my own question.**

First added variable to store the location value in `CGPoint`

```
var markerPosition : CGPoint!
```

- Then convert `CLLocationCoordinate2D` Location values into the `CGPoint` and store into `markerPosition` in **didEndDragging marker** method.

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didEndDragging marker: GMSMarker) {
        if marker == mapMarker{

            self.markerPosition = self.mapView.projection.point(for: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: marker.position.latitude, longitude: marker.position.longitude))

            print("End Dragging")
        }
    }
```

- After that set `GMSMarker` **position** at any screen point as per `CGPoint` values into the `MAPView`

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
     if self.markerPosition == nil{
         //To set pin into the center of mapview
         mapMarker.position = position.target 

     }else{
         //To set pin into the any particular point of the screen on mapview
         let coordinate = self.mapView.projection.coordinate(for: self.markerPosition)
         mapMarker.position = coordinate
     }
 }
```